# log4net:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config

Tags: c#, log4net

I have created a separate console application for the logging and then added that single console dll to more than one application for logging. As soon as I run the application, it is logging well but also showing the following error

```
 log4net:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <configSections> elements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

log4net:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the  and  elements. The configuration section should look like:

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
...

</configuration>
```

to your app/web.config file

Comment: I have used a third log.config file and added all the configuration into that file and  load that config file.

Comment: than show you do you load that config file?are you sure that configuration works before your first logging?

Answer (score 1):

First guess: The application, you add your dll to doesn't have a log4net config section in its configuration file. If that's the case either add a log4net config section to the application's config or use another way to configure log4net (eg. read config from a file which is always next to your dll, however the preferred way is to have all the config in one place, so I recommend adding a section to the app's config).

Comment: Yes, that dll have different config file for the log configuration.